# Java client can't find master node: MasterNotDiscoveredException waited for [1m]

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, vagrant

I'm using vagrant and I installed ES on it using the debian package:

```
elasticsearch-1.1.1.deb
```

In my web app, I am using the jar:

```
org.elasticsearch elasticsearch 1.1.1
```

I am creating my client like:

```
val node = nodeBuilder.client(true).node
val client: Client = node.client
```

When I try and index I get the error:

```
val response = client.prepareIndex("articles", "article", article.id.toString).setSource(json).execute.actionGet
```

**The error I get is:**

```
[MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [1m]]
```

I can see my ES instance is working fine by going to:

```
http://localhost:9200
```

I ran some test queries from the README file and they worked fine, but now for some reason it isn't working either:

```
http://localhost:9200/twitter/user/kimchy?pretty=true
```

I get the error:

```
{
  "error" : "ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];]",
  "status" : 503
}
```

My vagrant file 2 ports open for elastic search:

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 9200 # ES
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9300, host: 9300 # ES
```

What seems to be the problem?

Note: my web application isn't using a elasticsearch.yml file because it is just connecting to the default localhost:9200 from what I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have to connect to ES from outside through http (normally, but there are also others protocols available) and then talk REST/JSON. So your webapp should use a scala/java ES client (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/clients.html) and then connect via http to your host which is running ES on port 9200. Port 9300 is only for internode communication (ES is a distributed clustered system). But there is another way to talk remotely to ES: Powerup a node which joins the cluster and then query this node through the internal client. But:

In your above question you try to connect to ES through the internal Java client (internal transport) which starts a node and then try to joins the cluster. That fails because the master node could to be found. Maybe due to networking issues. Try to include elasticsearch.yml in the classpath or use REST like described above. There is also a third option: TransportClient - look http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#transport-client

See also http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html and http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html and http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-memcached.html

Comment: I am not using transport client, I am  using node client.  Transport client has ```InetSocketTransportAddress``` etc. which I don't.  My code is from the node client sample in the link you gave: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#transport-client

Answer (score 1):

Since you are generating your client node with `.client(true)`, that disables both data-storage and master-eligibility on your node, if I understand [the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#node-client) correctly. (the source is not very helpful either)

Note that any ES cluster needs at least 1 master node.

First, to clarify the config situation, your main `elasticsearch.yml` (see [reference config](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/config/elasticsearch.yml)) configuration is under `/etc/elasticsearch/`. You can also configure a second `elasticsearch.yml` in your `src/main/resources` folder, which will apply to the nodes you create in your app. I'd recommend doing this as it's way clearer compared to using the mysterious nodeBuilder methods.

Can you show what is the response when you query, right after starting es up, `http://localhost:9200/_nodes` ?
Specifically, if you have

```
"attributes": {
    "master": "true"
},
```

set on one of the nodes. If so, then it looks like a networking problem as your client node is unable to contact the master node. I actually had a similar issue when I was setting up, and the solution was to set `network.host: 127.0.0.1` in the app's `elasticsearch.yml` (wish I knew why)

Comment: Correction (checked my config) both sets of `elasticsearch.yml` need to have `network.host: 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

uncomment `discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false` in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`