# No data indexed using ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the following java code:

```
            Node node  = nodeBuilder().clusterName("mycluster").node();
            Client client = node.client();
String json = "{" +
        "\"user\":\"kimchy\"," +
        "\"postDate\":\"2013-01-30\"," +
        "\"message\":\"trying out Elasticsearch\"" +
    "}";

IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet")
        .setSource(json)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

I see that no "twitter" index gets created, and no document. Is there another step I have to do after this?

When I add a ".client(true)", I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [1m]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:520)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java-client-cant-find-master-node-masternotdiscoveredexception-waited-for-1m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253224/java-client-cant-find-master-node-masternotdiscoveredexception-waited-for-1m)

Comment: Possible, though the answers posted there do not address my problem.